# What happens at the end of Akira?

Tags: ending, akira

I've watched Akira at least seven times and each time I pick up something new from it. Last night I watched it again and wondered about the ending: do Akira, Tetsuo, Masaru, Kiyoko and Takashi merge and create a new universe? There's a few hints such as this quote from Doctor Onishi when Akiras energy pattern begins to compress into a singularity:

> W-What's happening?
>   What in the world is happening?
>   B-But this isn't...
>   If this is correct, it's almost as if...
>   Is this the birth of a universe?!

[When the credits roll we see what looks like the big bang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VROyZ8IuYhk), do they become god of a new universe?

Comment: I don't recall, it's been a long time ago when I watched it.  However, it might be worth mentioning that the English subtitles to the Japanese language version are a lot closer in meaning/intent to the original graphic novel than the dubbed English. (and yes, I recognise the irony of judging this against the English translation of the original Japanese graphic novel...).  In summary, see if the English subtitles offer a clearer picture of the ending.

Comment: I've always disliked the dubbed version, I was watching the subbed version

Comment: Good man.  Creating a new universe does seem a bit extreme, even for Akira and Tetsuo.

Comment: The translation in the dubbed version is dumbed down for western audiences. I know it seems extreme but watch the film again I think that's what happens. Yet to read the manga which might give more of a clue to what really happens.

Comment: I did own the graphic novels, but sold them a few years ago while they were still worth money.  Otherwise, I would have checked it out for you.  I imagine that they're scanned online somewhere though.

Answer (score 2):

I know someone who viewed every version of this he could get his hands on (manga, original, dub and sub), who said that every version was somewhat different - which agrees with  Alan Sutherland's comment that "the dubbed version is dumbed down for western audiences". I don't recall the "birth of a universe" line from the version I saw, but it's been years...